# Newbie Sharepoint website question

Tags: sharepoint

I am used to building java web applications.
I am used to MCV.
As I learn how to build a Sharepoint site, is it ok to think of building Sharepoint sites similarly, particulary where there is business logic layer, that, for instance, would grab data from various DBs, do some logic, then go to a certain page?

Comment: how about the question this way...having built plain MVC java web appls, what will i not be able to do in building a sharepoint site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint and MVC do not play well together, not in a supported way at least.  This isn't going to change for 2010 either.  It's an ASP.Net Web Forms app, and so acts accordingly.

Comment: i am also not familiar with ASP.NET Web Forms applications. Given I am a java developer, is it possible to give me so differences between a standard java mvc web app and a Web Forms app?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Open Source Project for [SharePoint MVC](http://sharepointmvc.codeplex.com/) but you need to understand the plataform first, with some [SharePoint for Developers](http://www.benkotips.com/Default.aspx?tabid=1158) tutorials.